# JSONObject from Google Maps parse in Java

Tags: java, json, org.json

I'm trying to parse Java Object to get data from a URL. I'm using `getJSONObject` and `getString` methods from `org.json.JSONObject` library but this it's not working. I'm doing something like...

```
JSONObject jsonCoord = json.getJSONObject("results")
                .getJSONObject("geometry")
                .getJSONObject("location");

coordinates[0] = jsonCoord.getString("lat");
coordinates[1] = jsonCoord.getString("lng");
```

[JSON document I want to parse (Part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyr9t.png)

[JSON document I want to parse (Part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86741.png)

How can I get "lat" and "lng" which is inside of "geometry"?

Comment: Please add JSON as text, not a picture. What exactly is not working? Any error?

Comment: Sorry, but you won't let me put text because it tells me it's too much code. 

Since the JSON object doesn't find the variable in which I try to save that object is null, so nothing works. P.S.: I'm new here.

Comment: Then please use https://jsonblob.com or similar to share JSON

Comment: Thanks!! JSON URL: https://jsonblob.com/6215ce4b-1323-11e9-b2cc-370cd88fda39

Comment: lat and lng aren't strings, they're decimal numbers. Some libraries would allow getting them as String, but I guess org.json.JSONObject doesn't. You should try getDouble instead

Comment: Oh, more importantly. results is an array of 1 element. You need getJSONObject(0) before getJSONObject("geometry")

Comment: Sorry, the problem comes from before. I did something like: if (json.getString("status").equals("OK")) { //TODO } and it didn't detect the "ok" either. Anyway, that last thing you said to me was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.json")), "UTF-8");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(content);
    JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("results");
    JSONObject result = (JSONObject) results.get(0); //or iterate if you need for each
    JSONObject jsonCoord = result.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
    System.out.println(jsonCoord);

    String[] coordinates = new String[2];
    coordinates [0] = jsonCoord.getString("lat");
    coordinates[1] = jsonCoord.getString("lng");

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(coordinates));

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It throws me an error indicating that "JSONObject["results"] not found"

Comment: Ok. could you please add system out for content? Maybe you are not getting the content itself or getting say empty one